# Export svg and the margin disappears

Tags: export

```
Fig = Plot[y = x, {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> {400, 300}, ImagePadding -> {{40, 20}, {30, 15}}]
Export["Fig.svg", Fig, "svg"]
```

[image]

The figure is like this with margin. However, when I insert it in Powerpoint (office2016), the margin is cut like below.

[image]

How to avoid this to make sure the image in ppt is exactly like in mathematica?

Comment: I tried this in MacOS with Mathematica 11.3 and opened the file in both Google Chrome and Inkscape. Both those programs tell me that Mathematica did keep the margin/padding when it exported the figure. What happens if you open the file in other programs than PowerPoint?

Comment: My Mathematica is 10(windows). I use Chrome open the file, and it shows width="380pt" height="251pt" , not 400x300. I try to use Mathematica 11.1, same issue.

Comment: Mathmatica 11.3 has fixed this bug.